# Why use Cookie with MemcacheD for Sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, memcached

I'm reading this [article](http://www.designdisclosure.com/2009/11/symfony-apc-cache-and-memcache-session-storage/)

Is there a reason why we need to use cookie with MemcacheD for Session management?

Can I not just use MemcacheD as a storage?

Comment: You need the cookie on the client to store the ID of the user's session. Without that cookie, it'd be impossible to tell one user from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you must send a cookie to the client in order to create a useful session. Otherwise, the client cannot reliably identify themselves from request to request (i.e. no ability to identify their session, no statefulness). Whether or not you simply store the ID of that session, or other information in the cookie, and what the lifetime of a session is either on the server side or the client side, is up to you.